# Necessary condition for a subgroup to be a Hall subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H \le G$ of order $m$. Assume that we have the following property:

**P:** For all $g \in G$,  $o(g) | m$ if and only if  $g$ lies in some conjugate of $H$.

Under this assumption, can we conclude that $H$ is a Hall subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Yes, that implies that $H^x$ is a normal subgroup, so $H^x=H$.

Comment: @DerekHolt  Thanks for your answer, but i didn't mean $x$ is fixed for all $g \in G$. I think the edited version of the question is more clear.

Comment: We could just take $G$ cyclic of order $4$ and $|H|=2$.

Answer (score 1):

No. As examples mentioned in the commentary, a  subgroup  of order p
of a cyclic group of order $p^n,  n>1$ is not a Hall subgroup, but
it satisfies the property P.